# Run downloaded .exe files in R, says it already exists

Tags: r

I wrote a R script to download a series of files such as this one:
ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/DeltaOpcoes/DO091203.ex_

The R code is as follows:

`url = "ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/DeltaOpcoes/DO091203.ex_";
destfile = "../Database/DO091203.ex_";
download.file(url,destfile,method="curl");
file.rename(destfile,"../Database/DO091203.exe")`

Then I am trying to run the .exe file using the 'system' function in R:

`string = 'C:\\Users\\Database\\DO091203.exe'
system(shQuote(string,type='cmd'))`

However R returns the following error: "PKZIP: (W7) Warning! file: DeltaOpcoes.txt already exists."

Nevertheless when I run these lines at the Command prompt, they work just fine:

`cd C:\\Users\\Database\\
start DO091203.exe`

Can anyone please help me to open this file in R so I can use it in a loop? Many thanks!

EDIT: This is the output of SessionInfo():

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) 
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] XLConnect_0.2-15     XLConnectJars_0.2-15

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0    yaml_2.1.19    rJava_0.9-9
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of `SessionInfo()`?

Comment: I edited the post with the output of SessionInfo() as it did not fit into a comment.